# How do I run SQL Scripts after DB Initialized from Docker-Compose?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, docker-compose

I have the Docker Compose file below. I'm trying to run the following:

- Set up Postgres
- Run Entity Framework to set up my schemas/tables
- Set up PG Admin
- Run some SQL scripts on the database.

The I can get the first three items done no problem, but I'm not sure where to put the running of my SQL scripts.  Right now it's on the last line of the YAML, but I'm sure this is wrong.  Where would I put this?  I'm not sure how to reference the database I'd set up earlier to run the SQL on.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  #SET UP POSTGRES
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: marmalade
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: marmalade
      POSTGRES_DB: marmalade
    
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U marmalade"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  #RUN ENTITY FRAMEWORK TO INITIALIZE DATABASE
  db-migrator:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}db-migrator
    build:
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: src/marmalade/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=IntegrationTest
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        
  #SET UP PGADMIN
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: marmalade
   
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
       - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json # preconfigured servers/connections
       - ./sql/admin_schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/admin_schema.sql  #<-  WHERE DO I PUT THIS?
```

Answer (score 0):

Its correct but it needs to be in your Db service

Example:

```
services:
    my_db:
      image: postgres:latest    
      volumes:
          - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

UPDATE:

problem with running in any other service is that its not going to have the credentials to connect to the database. So you can just create a shell script and run it the old fashioned way like so:

```
services:
    some_service:
        image: your_image    
        volume: ./init.sh:/init.sh
        entrypoint: sh -c "/init.sh"
```

assuming of course that you have the shell already installed in your image

Comment: I can't put it there because the db_migrator hasn't run yet, so none of the tables have been created.  I tried - and pg_admin comes up but there is no data in the tables.

Comment: @kickinchicken You probably cant run it in the pgadmin service. I added an update if that works

Comment: thanks.  I'm going to look at adding the shell to my image and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry - How would I check that?  I don't see a reference to a shell in my Dockerfile, but the application is running in a linux environment.  Is there no way to login to the DB after the tables have been set up?

Comment: @kickinchicken what do you use as a starting image for your dockerfile? if you are using CentOS or alpine etc then they should already have it. One way to check is to just run the image locally with a shell at the end `docker run -it image-name sh`. If this doesnt work just add a simple sh command in the dockerfile and see if it builds `RUN echo hello-world`